# Unable to see "StartsWith" on Criteria Based Sharing Rule on the UI, even though it is successfully deployed to the org

Tags: apex, sharing, sharing-rule

I have a situation in which I had to create a Criteria Based Sharing Rule with **"StartsWith"** for a field. However, the only option via the UI I see available as operator are **Equals** & **Not Equals**. When I created the Rule via metadata and pushed it to the org it worked and I can see the Rule.

But when I chose to Edit the Rule, the Criteria with **"StartsWith"** option shows operator as **--none--.**
Does anyone know what is this strange behavior about?

Comment: Is the field a picklist field? - if yes, only `equals` and `not equals` are supported

Comment: Thanks @cropredy, yes indeed its a picklist field

Comment: Does it mean I need to use a formula field to be able to use startsWith Clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have a picklist field ...

- If your criteria requires use of a picklist field, you can only use equals/not equals.
- Using a formula field won't help (i.e. `TEXT(MyPicklist__c)`) as criteria can't be used against a formula
- You'll need to use a trigger or process automation to set a shadow text field that is synchronized to the picklist value to be able to use Starts With operator in Sharing criteria.

  - *HOWEVER - If you rename picklist field entries, your automation/trigger will never know that behind the scenes, SFDC has converted the database data to the new picklist value and your synchronization strategy will require a one-time data loader exercise.*
- An alternative workaround is to enumerate the picklist values in the sharing criteria
- Another alternative is a shadow checkbox field `Is_Enabled_For_Sharing__c` that you manage with a trigger/process automation. Same caveat about detection  of picklist entry value changes.

Note also that for text fields ...

- If your criteria requires use of a Shield-encrypted field you are out of luck.